# Pandas.Dataframe to hd5 FIle

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I try to write a Pandas dataframe to HD%-File via

```
df.to_hdf(pfad,format='table','df')
```

to query it later on but get  SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that `'df'` which is a non-keyword (regular) argument can't appear after `format='table'` which is a keyword argument. You probably want:

```
df.to_hdf(pfad, 'df', format='table')
```